# Launching .exe in its own directory with elevation priviledges

Tags: java, exe, elevated-privileges

My question is pretty simple, **I would like to launch a .exe in its own directory but with elevation rights/privileges.**
I know that this question as been raised before but I didn't found the right way for fixing my problem.

---

Indeed, I first tried this :

```
String workingDir = "C:\\TEST\\";
String cmd = workingDir + "game.exe";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd,null,new File(workingDir));
```

I got the following error:

```
CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
```

---

Then I tried this:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
    new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/C","C:\\TEST\\game.exe"});
Process newProcess = builder.start();
```

---

And it runs but not in its own directory. How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if this will work:

```
String workingDir = "C:\\TEST\\";
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
    new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/C",workingDir+"game.exe"}
  );
builder.directory(new File(workingDir));
Process newProcess = builder.start();
```

Comment: new File()  ? question : will this not delete my previous folder ? I have lot of datas stored in this, I do want to take the risk before running the code. Are you sure that it will not delete the previous folder "workingDir"? Thank you!

Comment: No, creating a new File object will not make any changes to the underlying files on disk, it just creates a representation of a file. To actually create a new file on disk there is an extra method call required (and even then, it should fail if the file already exists).

Comment: Ok, I've just tried and it works. Thank you very much. I don't know to who assign the correct answer since you both provided me the same and correct one. What should I do ? In any way, thank you for you help!

Comment: Which ever answer you think best describes the solution. If each answer only describes part of the solution, encourage the author to edit their answer to be more complete; or create your own answer that completely provides the solution and accept that.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want to set

```
builder.directory(new File("C:\\TEST"));
```

which

> Sets this process builder's working directory

---

Otherwise, it appears that for this to work you need to be Running as an Administrator.

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=CreateProcess+error%3D740%2C+The+requested+operation+requires+elevation

Comment: Not true, since I could run this exe file with *ProcessBuilder*, but not in its own directory, as written above.

Comment: Thank you for editing your answer. As written above, I have one worry about new File() ? question : will this not delete my previous folder ? I have lot of datas stored in this, I do want to take the risk before running the code. Are you sure that it will not delete the previous folder "workingDir"? Thank you!

Comment: Even if you accidentally call `new File("C:\\TEST").delete();` it won't delete the directory unless its empty (you have to delete every file and directory in it first). Sounds like you need a backup. ;) If you are not sure, I would try it with a small copy of the files you need. ;)

Comment: It works fine, thank you very much ! Since you both provided the same answer I didn't know to who assign the positive one. But I guess you less need points than fd. I hope you will understand. Thank you for your help anyway!!!

Comment: @user1633807 I would give rep to the lower points as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to elevate privileges of a forked process. You should start the new process with the account that has the rights you need

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps make a batch file with a cd and the command you want to run, then execute the batch file with cmd.